# Jquery td:eq(id) ignore child tables

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am using Jquery dataTables and in the  fnCreatedRow function I am creating the rows like this:

```
fnCreatedRow: function (nRow, aData, iDataIndex) {
                var e = Object.keys(aData);

  $('td:eq(0)', nRow).html("<label id='lbl_" + e[0] + "' class='display-mode'>" + aData[e[0]] + "</label>");
  $('td:eq(1)', nRow).html("<label id='lbl_" + e[1] + "' class='display-mode'>" + aData[e[1]] + "</label>");
  $('td:eq(2)', nRow).html("<label id='lbl_" + e[2] + "' class='display-mode'>" + aData[e[2]] + "</label>");
```

But the problem is if I have table with other tables inside that again in aData[e[1]] the td:eq(2) does not apply to the next cell but to a cell in the nested table.

So how can I be sure the $('td:eq(id)' always applies to just the first tr?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$(selector, context)` returns all the matching *descendants*, it works like the `find` method:

```
$(context).find(selector);
```

You could use the `children` method:

```
var $tds = $(nRow).children();

$tds.eq(0).html('...');
```